# How to use connect router without connect http server?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function:

```
function foo(request, response, next)
{
   ...
}
```

And I want to use the router from 'connect' npm library to route the request. However, I could only find in the documentation how to attach the router to the built-in HTTP server of connect. I want to do something like this:

```
var connect = require('connect')
function foo(request, response, next)
{
    connect.middleware.router(request, response, next, function (app)
    {
        app.get('/', ...)
        app.get('/openid/verify', ...)
        ...
    })
}
```

The question is: how do I pass request, response and next to connect router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
var connect = require('connect');

var router = connect.middleware.router(function (app) {
    app.get('/', ...)
    app.get('/openid/verify', ...)
});

function handleRequest(req, res, next) {
    router(req, res, next);
}
```